# Serial USB device with Windows drivers. Want to use it with linux

Tags: python, linux, serial-port

I have a GPS unit I can connect with USB, which is said by the manufacturer to be used with Windows. It has a CD with some drivers. Something about USB to Serial PL2303.

But I need to be able to use it with linux and python. How can I go on about trying to achieve this? Is it a lost cause when I have no documentation from manufacturer about which registers to read and such?

When I connect it is being recognized in dmesg, it gets a name /dev/ttyUSB1
What is the next step in trying to get this to work?

Comment: Do you have any clue about the GPS model ? If you get to know the COM connection parameters you can connect to it.

Comment: What do I need? I know the baud rate f.ex

Comment: should be enough ! Of course if you know any commands to send through the COM port would be good. But if you connect you may see some output from the GPS

Comment: Since it is a virtual USBtoCOM device, the baud rate is useless. Just open the device and read lines from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *easiest* way to do this is to use [gpsd](http://www.catb.org/gpsd/) to read the data from the device.  gpsd will automatically parse the messages from the GPS device and give you back the important information.  There are already Python bindings for you to get the information back, or you can fall back onto calling the C library from Python if that is required.

If you want to parse it yourself, it's likely the device is giving you out [NMEA 0183](http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm) data.  The most likely default settings are going to be `4800-8-N-1` or `9600-8-N-1`.  The easiest way that I have found to check devices such as this is to use GTKTerm to open up the serial port and see if the data is coming back properly.  Here's some sample data from a GPS receiver from USGlobalSat, running at 4800bps:

```
$GPGGA,,,,,,0,00,,,M,0.0,M,,0000*48
$GPGSA,M,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*12
$GPGSV,3,1,12,01,00,000,,02,00,000,,03,00,000,,04,00,000,*7C
$GPGSV,3,2,12,05,00,000,,06,00,000,,07,00,000,,08,00,000,*77
$GPGSV,3,3,12,09,00,000,,10,00,000,,11,00,000,,12,00,000,*71
$GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53
```